# Tomcat cluster with inconsistent static resources

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing

Suppose there's a java webapp that let users upload image files, it simply stores those images on the tomcat server's filesystem, and will serve them as static resources upon further requesting. Now this application needs to be scaled out and deployed in a large cluster of tomcat servers sitting behind an apache server with mod_jk as load-balancer.

Since the uploaded images lie on the filesystem, they won't be available on the rest of tomcat servers other than the one on which the upload event occurs. If one user comes in, uploads an image,and after a while requests the image again, his request may be unfortunately routed to another server due to the round-robin load balancing policy, so he won't see his image!

Is there any conventional way to deal with this sort of problem? or should i re-design the upload system by utilizing a back-end database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't have a shared NFS drive and upload the images there? Assuming there will be no naming collisions, of course.

Comment: it's a deficient legacy cluster system, and i believe there're tons of name collisions. Anyway, nfs drive sounds interesting, i'll give it a try.

Comment: You could do something like a hashmap where each item has almost unique hash key but in case of collision another counter/id would guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a shared filesystem. Of course, thats not always possible. The other way is to hold everything in the database. Because of synchronization, this is the way I would suggest.
For content I would recommend to use jackrabbit. A good introduction to clustering and jackrabbit is here: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering